# TSQL Subquery for Column Names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use a set of query results for column names in a select statement?

Example, I have a table named TableA:

```
Column:    Type:
KeyOne     nvarchar(5)
KeyTwo     nvarchar(5)
```

TableB is another table, whose column names might be stored in TableA.

Suppose TableB is like this:

```
Column:    Type:
Val1       int
Val2       int
```

Is there any way I could do a query like this to get the columns?

```
SELECT (select TOP 1 KeyOne, KeyTwo FROM TableA)
FROM TableB
```

Another example using strings would be like this:

```
SELECT (select 'Val1', 'Val2')
FROM TableB
```

---

Is this possible in any way without concatenated SQL?

Comment: It will require dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GoatCO Was hoping to stay away from that if possible.  Oh well.  Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only do this with dynamic SQL, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 KeyOne+','+KeyTwo FROM TableA)
       ,@sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@cols+' FROM TableB'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up putting my initial query into a temporary table, and turning my dynamic columns into a string seperated by commas and running a dynamic sql select to get the selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can read table column names dynamically from sys.columns system views or using other management views

```
select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(N'TableName')
```

Then by creating a [dynamic SQL query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) you can create your own select